# How to configure an Android thread before starting it?

Tags: android

Let say I want to pass some configuration data before I start a thread so it can run with it right away how do I do that?  Here is a simple code:

Here I'm trying to configure the sleep delay, but it requires me to declare data inside?  How can I let the thread know?

```
public void startAniHandlerThread(){

    int sleeptime;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {

                sleep(sleeptime); Log.d("TEST", " Test ");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("TEST", " "+e);
            }
        }
    };
    thread1.start();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare sleeptime as

```
final int sleeptime = <value>;
```

That way you'll be able to access it from inside the Runnable.